# Query to replace each value of a list

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I want to write an athena query that results in a table that replaces each of the value in the **`list_ids`** array with the **`original_id`**.

Comment: What is the DDL that created these tables? It would be helpful to know the column types. I presume that Table1.content_ids is a JSON column? Or is it text?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to one of my colleagues, a better, concise solution for the whole problem described by you including the struct column.

```
SELECT id, TRANSFORM(content_ids, id -> m[id]),
 TRANSFORM_VALUES(cast(t1.popular_ids as MAP(VARCHAR,ARRAY(VARCHAR))), (k,arr) ->  TRANSFORM(arr, v -> m[v]))
FROM t1, (SELECT MAP_AGG(content_id, original_id) as m FROM t2) t;
```

From table t2, we use MAP_AGG function to create a MAP 'm' of content_id and original_id. We then use TRANSFORM and lambda to transform array of content_ids to original_ids using this map, and use TRANSFORM_VALUES to transform the JSON first by CASTing it to MAP(VARCHAR,ARRAY(VARCHAR)), then lambda to transform each ARRAY in turn using TRANSFORM again.

---

Below is the first solution.

```
SELECT t1.id, ARRAY_AGG(t2.original_id) 
FROM t1 CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t1.content_ids) as t(content_id) 
JOIN t2 on t2.content_id = t.content_id 
GROUP BY t1.id;

|  id   |   _col1.    |
|-------|-------------|
| uid_1 | [O_1, O_2]  |

(1 row)
```

The first part of the query unnests the array.

```
SELECT id, content_id FROM t1 CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t1.content_ids) as t(content_id);
|  id   | content_id|
------- |-----------|
| uid_1 | 1         |
| uid_1 | 2         |
```

Now that content_ids array is unnested, the second part joins the unnested content_id in t1 with t2 on t2.content_id.

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.original_id FROM t1 CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t1.content_ids) as t(content_id) JOIN t2 on t2.content_id = t.content_id;
 
| id   | original_id   |
|-------|------------- |
| uid_1 | O_1          |
| uid_1 | O_2          |
```

### Now original_id is derived for each id independently. To convert it back to the array, we do ARRAY_AGG operation on original_id grouping by id. That's the final query.

Comment: Thanks Naveen. It would be helpful if you could break down the query and explain it. I need to modify it as I have another column same as content_ids named popular_ids  and it also needs to be processed. How can I apply unnest to two columns?

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: running into the error

Cannot cast row(popular_ids_1 array(varchar),popular_ids _2array(varchar),popular_ids_3 array(varchar)) to map(varchar,array(varchar))